# Rails Acts As Commentable, Support for multiple Models? AJAX?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm interested in adding commenting to my Rails 3 app. Acts As Commentable seems to be best choice out there even though it's a little dated?

I'd like your input on

1. Can Acts as Commentable support multiple models? Example, I want commenting on items Like Books, Authors, Chapters, etc.. which are all separate pages. Is this possible with the plugin?
2. It seems like this plugin is just the model for comments and then being able to create & access comments. If I want to then add this to one of my views (books for example) where do I start? Also, I want comments to be postable via AJAX. Where do I start to learn how to implement such a thing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Acts as Commentable does support multiple models.
I think you can start to learn by looking a look at the plugin read me itself.

Thanks, Anubhaw

Comment: Anything on the 2nd question... Actually implementing the plugin on the views?